# Excel Downloading a File using VBS and Batch, Can't Download file from VBS

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

Hello Stacked Overflow Community,

This question has been asked before, but not with one specific element involved; ***Automation* through VBS**

1. To summarize I have a file I wish to download everyday automatically
2. There is a known username & password
3. The download file is from an actual button with no associated URL (*HTMLButton.Click*)
4. I'm using *SendKeys* to perform the save file operation to get past the window "Do you want to open or save your file"
5. Everything works when performed within the macro (Running from Excel);
6. However, I want this to function with the windows Task Scheduler and I have written a batch file that calls a Visual Basic Script to the above and of course **breaks on the step 4**

Batch Code:

```
@echo off
echo Success! Code ALG_Excel_01 %date:~-10,2%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~-2,2% ^& %time:~0,8% >> "C:\Users\dchacon\Desktop\ALG_DCCS02\Logs_DCCS02.txt"
cscript C:\Users\dchacon\Desktop\ALG_DCCS02\ALG_Excel_01.vbs
timeout 7
exit
```

VBS Code:

```
Dim objExcel, objWB
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dchacon\Desktop\ALG_DCCS02\ALG_Triple_Check.xlsm")
ObjWB.Application.Run("ExportSequence")

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
'Set ObjExcel = Nothing
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
'WScript.Echo "Finished."
'WScript.Quit
```

VBA Code:

```
Sub ExportSequence()
    
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLLogin As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLPassword As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLFrom As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTo As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLJob As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim URL As String
    
    URL = "https://Vendor_Website.com/login.aspx"
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate URL
    
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> ReadyState_Complete
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
    Set HTMLLogin = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uxAlgLogin$txtUserName")
    Set HTMLPassword = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uxAlgLogin$txtPassword")
    HTMLLogin.Value = "UserName"
    HTMLPassword.Value = "Password"

    Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_uxAlgLogin_lnkLogin")
    HTMLButton.Click
    
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> ReadyState_Complete
    Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    
    '****New Logic**********
    Set HTMLFrom = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPoolDateStart")
    Set HTMLTo = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPoolDateEnd")
    Set HTMLJob = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtJobNum")
    Set HTMLName = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtJobName")
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
    HTMLFrom.Value = "1/01/2021"
    HTMLTo.Value = "7/30/2021"
    'HTMLJob.Value = str_Job
    'HTMLName.Value = str_Name
    
    '***Search Button****
    Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnSearch")
    HTMLButton.Click
    
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> ReadyState_Complete
    Loop
        
    '***Export Button Sequence***
    Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnExport")
    HTMLButton.Click
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))
    'Debug.Print ie.ReadyState, ie.Application, ie.Document, ie.Container
    
    'Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
    SendKeys "%S"
    'Call Download
    
End Sub
```

I put in both Do while <> ReadyState_Complete & Application.Wait and I understand it's redundant but the code works well throughout. The biggest issue is the SendKeys "%S" which I can't seem to get functioning when I call the code through VBS. As long as it can work through VBS it would be fine as I know the batch trigger will execute well; I just figured why not include it and share what I think is actually pretty cool code. I have experimented with trying to call and change the foreground window but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

[Annoyingly Impossible Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo1GT.png)

[Click Button Inspect Element Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XYdo.png)

[Folder with all Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp23q.png)

Comment: Pretty good explanation but you forgot one thing.  How is the scheduled task configured?

Comment: The task is running; I have no issue triggering the batch file, I have logs written everytime the code is executed from the batch with ```echo Success!``` Line

Comment: There may some trouble exists on MS Application execution for Task Scheduller session. Use this [solution "create **Desktop**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973937/)

Comment: Very interesting Link @Daemon-5 I have experienced issues before running MS Excel through the non-interactive user; however, I am running the Task Scheduler with the current user to avoid those issues. Maybe I should clarify further in my original statement but the **problem is when VBS calls the Excel Macro**. And the entire macro executes, just I don't know how to point to the Internet Explorer application and force it to save the document. So either I **need code in the VBS or in the VBA and it directly has to do with Forcing the app to save the file**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not full answer to your question. But I cannot add this VBA-code to comments.
I used this procedure to **forcely** resave files from xlsm/xls/xlsb to xlsx. Input parameter is the fullname of file to resave.

```
Function procSaveAS(fn As String) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo ErrSt
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn, _
       AddToMru:=False, Notify:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   st = LCase(Right(fn, 4))
   fnn = fn
   If st = "xlsm" Or st = "xlsb" Then
    fnn = Left(fnn, Len(fnn) - 1)
    
   End If
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fnn & "x", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
      ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    procSaveAS = True
    Exit Function
ErrSt:
    procSaveAS = False
End Function
```

P.S. After successful procedure call I killed the source file.